# couldnt find out why my program is crashing in c

Tags: c, arrays

Using Dev C++ on windows 7 64 bit

I was trying to implement a c program that identifies the word with most occurrences in a sentence in the most optimal way.
This is what i created..

```
 struct word{
    char *str;
    int count;
    };

int main()
{
    struct word words[10]={0};
    int i,j,flag=0,max=0;
    char *maxw=NULL,*arr[] = {"how","do","you","do"};


    for(i=0;arr[i];i++)
    {
        flag =0;
        for(j=0;words[j].count!=0;j++)
            if(strcmp(words[j].str,arr[i]) == 0 )
            {
                words[j].count++;
                flag = 1;
                break;
            }

        if(flag == 0){  
        words[j].str = arr[i];
        words[j].count++;
        }

        if (max < words[j].count){
        max = words[j].count;
        maxw=words[j].str;
        }
    }
    printf("\nMost occurrences is of %s with %d count",maxw,max);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

What i have figured out already is that the program crashes only when the maximum occurring word is the also the last word of the sentence and this has something to do with addresses of fixed strings in the memory. But i am not sure exactly what is happening here. Also, is this a good solution to this problem or some more optimum solution exists ??

P.S. This is not homework i am just practicing some coding.

Comment: `*arr[] = {"how","do","you","do", NULL}; BTW: this is the kind of bug that you can avoid by using printf-debugging.

Comment: `for(i=0;arr[i];i++)`  Don't you think anything is wrong here?

Comment: If you do not put the array as @wildplasser said, then the for loop: ``for(i=0;arr[i];i++)`` will become dangerous.It will never find anything NULL to stop looping ever and will access out-of-bound memory causing crash.

Comment: @wildplasser Thanx.. i will use such notation in future...

Comment: @nims: See wildplassers comment.

Comment: But my problem still remains... I figured out what the problem is and was trying to understand the reason. Is it because how the pointer arrays are advanced by adding the index to the base address causing the pointer to reset to some earlier position?? If now, then why does the following works perfectly fine:
*arr[] = {"how","do","you","do", "partner"};

Comment: Maybe it works by coincidence? As a loop condition you can either use a treshold value: `for (i=0; i < 4; i++){}` or you use a sentinel-value: `for (i=0; arr[i] != NULL; i++) {}`. In both cases you must ensure that the end-condition is actually reached (unless you want an infinite loop).

Comment: checked with many different inputs. The program crash only when the last word is the one with the max occurrences. There must be an explanation for this. Anyways, i learned how to deal with such situations... thanx for that....

Comment: You are using for loop. By rule, a for loop is: for((optional);(mandatory);(optional)). The mandatory part of the for loop,is there for a reason. It must contain a valid expression and unless you want a unpredictably behaving for loop, you have to do what @wildplasser said. Put a proper end-condition there.

Comment: Yes, there is an explanation for this. (I stopped reading at the first error I encountered). I would suggest you put the insert-new-word or increment-existing-word functionality inside a separate function, and call that from the main main loop.

Comment: the inner J loop never terminates either...

Answer (score 3):

Your array of pointers is not null terminated, but in your loop you are checking for null like :

```
for(i=0;arr[i];i++)
```

So you should null terminate your `arr` like

```
char *maxw=NULL,*arr[] = {"how","do","you","do",NULL}
```